# How to convert array of int to bin int?

Tags: c, binary

I got array filled zeros and ones, how can i convert it to int;

From: `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}`
To this `0b00000001`

Comment: Some code doing some bit setting/shifting is probably a worthy endeavor That's what I'd try, anyway. What did *you* try ?

Comment: "I tried", "it doesn’t work out very well". Please show what you tried and explain how it failed. Then helping you is much easier. Make a [mre] of what you have. (Try to avoid the impression that you quote a homework assignment. If it actually is a homework have a look here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions ) As it currently is your question lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying to program this yourself.

Comment: @Yunnosch If trying shift `1 << 0b00000000` and then add 1 it's gonna be like `0b00000001`. I need `0b00000010`

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose a decimal number as follows:

456<sub>10</sub> = 4 * 10<sup>2</sup> + 5 * 10<sup>1</sup> + 6 * 10<sup>0</sup>

Same for binary numbers

00000001<sub>2</sub> = 0 * 2<sup>7</sup> + ... + 0 * 2<sup>1</sup> + 1 * 2<sup>0</sup>

You effectively start with the decomposed form. To get back the integer from the decomposed bits, just apply that formula.

```
i =
(a[0] * 0b10000000) +
(a[1] * 0b01000000) +
(a[2] * 0b00100000) +
(a[3] * 0b00010000) +
(a[4] * 0b00001000) +
(a[5] * 0b00000100) +
(a[6] * 0b00000010) +
(a[7] * 0b00000001);
```

Remember that multiplying by a power of 2 is the same as shifting that power. And since the additions never produce a carry, we can use `|` instead of `+`. So we can write the above as follows:

```
i =
(a[0] << 7) |
(a[1] << 6) |
(a[2] << 5) |
(a[3] << 4) |
(a[4] << 3) |
(a[5] << 2) |
(a[6] << 1) |
(a[7] << 0);
```

Or as follows:

```
i =              a[0];
i = ( i << 1 ) | a[1];
i = ( i << 1 ) | a[2];
i = ( i << 1 ) | a[3];
i = ( i << 1 ) | a[4];
i = ( i << 1 ) | a[5];
i = ( i << 1 ) | a[6];
i = ( i << 1 ) | a[7];
```

Feel free to use a loop.

Comment: @Sam that's the idea. You can use a loop, with index running from MSB (sizeof(array) - 1) down to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use add(+1) and left shift(<<) to implement this function,
like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int shift(int list[], int count){
    int res = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        res<<=1;
        if(list[i]){
            res = res + 1;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main(){
    int bins [] = {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1};
    int bin = shift(bins, sizeof(bins)/sizeof(int));
    printf("%x\n",bin);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you may also bit operation like or(|) instead of add(+1). The performance should be similar.

Hopefully this can be helpful.